# Android Server wont run

Tags: android, sockets

My server wont connect/run at all.

```
package com.example.brooklynxman.hobo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Loading extends ActionBarActivity {
    int gort1=0;
    int numDates=0;
    String d1="";
    String d2="";
    String result = "";
    Button bcont;
    boolean done = false;
    boolean validity=true;
    Intent intent;
    int numPages=0;
    Socket s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        intent = getIntent();
        numDates=intent.getIntExtra("numDates",0);
        d1=intent.getStringExtra("date1");
        if (numDates ==2) {
            d2=intent.getStringExtra("date2");
        }
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("userinput", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("done",false);
        editor.putString("date1",d1);
        editor.putString("date2", d2);
        editor.putInt("numDates", numDates);
        bcont= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        bcont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (done) {
                    if (validity) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TableDisplay.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("results", result);
                        myIntent.putExtra("numPages", numPages);
                        myIntent.putExtra("page", 0);
                        Loading.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    } else {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        Loading.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //connect();
        //tempover();
        try {
            connect();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (sp.getBoolean("done",true)) {
            if (result.equals("")) {
                result = sp.getString("results", "");
                if (!result.equals("")) {
                    numPages = sp.getInt("numPages", 0);
                    validity = true;
                } else {
                    validity = false;
                }
                bcont.setText("Complete");
                done = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            done = true;
            validity=false;
        }
    }


    private void connect() throws IOException{
        MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask();
        myClientTask.execute();
        /*SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("userinput", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        String date1;
        String date2 = "";
        int numDate = sp.getInt("NumDate",0);
        int gort = sp.getInt("gort",0);
        if (numDate==1) {
            date1 = sp.getString("Date","");
        }
        else {
            date1 = sp.getString("Date1","");
            date2=sp.getString("Date2","");
        }*/
        /*new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    String SERVER_IP="73.23.84.77";
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                    s = new Socket(serverAddr, 5001);//add ip
                    //end
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())),
                            true);
                    //out.println(numDate);
                    out.print(numDates);
                    int m, d, y;
                    m = 0;
                    d = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    //convert to int;
                    if (d2.length() < 7) {
                        d2 = "00/00/00";
                    }
                    m = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(0, 2));
                    d = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(3, 5));
                    y = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(6, 8));
                    out.print(m);
                    out.print(d);
                    out.print(y);
                    if (numDates == 2) {
                        m = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(0, 2));
                        d = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(3, 5));
                        y = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(6, 8));
                        out.print(m);
                        out.print(d);
                        out.print(y);
                    }
                    out.print(0);
                    out.flush();
                    String valid = in.readLine();
                    if (!valid.equals("invalid")) {
                        result = in.readLine();
                        int l = result.length() - 221;
                        numPages = (l / 37) / 17;
                        out.close();
                        in.close();
                        s.close();
                        bcont.setText("Complete");
                        if (!result.equals("")) {
                            validity = true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                        s.close();
                        validity = false;
                    }
                    done = true;
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        /*try {
            String SERVER_IP="73.23.84.77";
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            s = new Socket(serverAddr, 5001);//add ip
            //end
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            //out.println(numDate);
            out.print(numDates);
            int m, d, y;
            m = 0;
            d = 0;
            y = 0;
            //convert to int;
            if (d2.length() < 7) {
                d2 = "00/00/00";
            }
            m = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(0, 2));
            d = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(3, 5));
            y = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(6, 8));
            out.print(m);
            out.print(d);
            out.print(y);
            if (numDates == 2) {
                m = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(0, 2));
                d = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(3, 5));
                y = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(6, 8));
                out.print(m);
                out.print(d);
                out.print(y);
            }
            out.print(0);
            out.flush();
            String valid = in.readLine();
            if (!valid.equals("invalid")) {
                result = in.readLine();
                int l = result.length() - 221;
                numPages = (l / 37) / 17;
                out.close();
                in.close();
                s.close();
                bcont.setText("Complete");
                if (!result.equals("")) {
                    validity = true;
                }
            } else {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                s.close();
                validity = false;
            }
            done = true;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }


    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        MyClientTask(){
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            SharedPreferences spx;
            spx = getSharedPreferences("userinput", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = spx.edit();
        /*editor.putBoolean("done",false);
        editor.putString("date1",d1);
        editor.putString("date2", d2);
        editor.putInt("numDates", numDates);*/
            Socket s = null;

            try {
                String SERVER_IP="127.00.0.1";//not the ip in the actual program
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                s = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);//add ip
                //end
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                //out.println(numDate);
                out.print(numDates);
                int m, d, y;
                m = 0;
                d = 0;
                y = 0;
                //convert to int;
                if (d2.length() < 7) {
                    d2 = "00/00/00";
                }
                m = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(0, 2));
                d = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(3, 5));
                y = Integer.parseInt(d1.substring(6, 8));
                out.print(m);
                out.print(d);
                out.print(y);
                if (numDates == 2) {
                    m = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(0, 2));
                    d = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(3, 5));
                    y = Integer.parseInt(d2.substring(6, 8));
                    out.print(m);
                    out.print(d);
                    out.print(y);
                }
                out.print(0);
                out.flush();
                String valid = in.readLine();
                if (!valid.equals("invalid")) {
                    result = in.readLine();
                    int l = result.length() - 221;
                    numPages = (l / 37) / 17;
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    s.close();
                    if (!result.equals("")) {
                        validity = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    s.close();
                    validity = false;
                }
                done = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ed.putString("results",result);
            ed.putInt("numPages",numPages);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }  
}
```

The server prints when a connection is made and nothing is happening, but the button says complete and redirects to the MainActivity. Ummm, some more details are yesterday I spent hours before finding out I need the socket in its own thread for android to run it wondering why it was crashing at the socket declaration line.

Comment: Dont see an error, What I see when I run is it changes the button to complete but clicking it runs back to the home screen. Checking the server which has the lines Socket HOBOSocket = HOBOServer.accept();System.out.println("in"); It never prints so nothing is connecting

Comment: Both IOException and UnknownHostException dont seem to be thrown (I set a string to e.toString() in case of both and set a textfield to dislplay them and nothing

Comment: Nope had an error, the error is ConnectException failed to connect to ip connect failed ECONNREFUSED

Comment: I think the port might be blocked on my wifi, will check back in a bit. If it is Ill add that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the IP wrong. Googling my IP gave me the wring address I needed the one in my network settings.

Comment: You might want to close the question then -- this won't be useful to anyone else.